# Sum of 4 digit numbers

Tags: combinatorics

What is the sum of all the numbers of 4 different digits that can be made using digits 0,1,2,3? How do you solve such problems? I am only familiar with basic combinatorics problems

Comment: Tell us what you have tried?

Comment: No, that would be a 3 digit number

Answer (score 3):

There are $3 \cdot 4^3=192$ numbers of this type.  The leading digits are $1,2,3$ equally, averaging $2$ so they sum to $192 \cdot 2000=384000$.  The other digits are $0,1,2,3$ equally, averaging $1.5$, so they sum to $1.5 \cdot 192 \cdot 111=31968$  The total is $415968$

Added:  If you want four digits with none repeated and leading zeros are not allowed, there are $18$ numbers.  The thousands digit averages $2$ and contributes $2 \cdot 1 \cdot 1000.$  The other digits average $1.5$ and contribute $24$ times their place, giving $36000+2400+240+24=38664$

Comment: The answer is 38664

Comment: @user34304:  That is over a factor $10$ below what Umberto and I got independently.  We are clearly not counting the things you are asking about.  Having $192$ numbers each at least $1000$ means the sum must be greater than $192000$.  Please update your question.  I suspect your numbers must be a permutation of $0123,$ that digits cannot be reused.

Comment: @user34304 I've just double-checked, and if the numbers have to be a permutation of 0123 and digits can't be reused, 38664 is indeed the result.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** : Let $x$ be the number of numbers with $0$ at the unit place, Let $y$ be the number of numbers with $1$ at the unit place and so on.

Then, sum at unit's place = $0.x + y + 2 w + 3z$

Comment: For 10, 100 and 1000 place, do we need to multiply by 10,100 and 1000 respectively?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I think so, because otherwise the sum would be very small. But I don't understand why?

Comment: The reason you need to be multiply by 10,100 and 1000 respectively is not because the sum will be very small. Can you relate to the decimal place value system and the process by which addition takes place for $n$ length numbers?

Comment: I am just not getting the answer, sir

Comment: Well, if you follow the procedure, you will get the answer. If a number $x = a_1a_2......a_n$, then the number can also be expressed as $10^0 . a_n + 10^1 . a_{n-1} + .... + 10^{n-1} a_1$ . You might have made the mistake of either (i) Not carrying over the carry generated at each place ( think of how addition takes place ) or (ii) not added together correctly

Comment: Ahhhh, now I get it. It's pretty simple, actually

Comment: The answer is I think 38664

Answer (score 0):

What we are doing is summing all 24 permutations of the digits {0, 1, 2, 3}, treating each as a four-digit number. Each column sums to 36. You might get close to your desired answer if you multiply 36 by 1111.

Comment: I think repeated digits are allowed and leading zeros are not allowed.

Comment: Why 1111, sir.?

Answer (score 0):

Being lazy and being late I tought I could let my laptop calculate it...

Result should be 415968

And is obtained with this very "stupid" and "unoptimized" code. I don't know if this is useful but I was curios...

```
#!/usr/bin/python

sum = 0
for a in range (1,4):
    for b in range (0,4):
        for c in range (0,4):
            for d in range (0,4):
                sum = sum + a*1000+b*100+c*10+d

print "Sum is: ", sum
```

Comment: Those ranges should be (1,3) and (0,3).

Comment: Well if in python you use range(0,3) you will only get the numbers 0,1,2 and not 3 as the original poster asked... Try the following code 

  #!/usr/bin/python
  for a in range (0,3): 
     print a
you will get (as output) 0 1 2.